# Pythonic way to change contents of 2 columns long dataframe after date

Tags: python, pandas

The "top" and "bottom" temp/humid sensor of Device "MOR4" were misplaced between on Aug 10 and 11.

What is the most pythonic way to correct this in the "long format" dataset?

data structure:

Data sample

```
data.head()
    bottom_temperature  bottom_humidity top_temperature top_humidity    external_temperature    published_at    external_humidity   short_id    weight
0   34.48   44.81   33.56   47.62   17.88   2017-10-07 23:11:27 17.88   MOR1    NaN
1   34.89   42.89   33.89   43.86   18.06   2017-10-09 03:16:05 18.06   MOR5    NaN
2   34.87   41.90   33.81   42.88   18.19   2017-10-09 03:31:41 18.19   MOR5    NaN
3   34.79   43.05   33.93   44.68   18.00   2017-10-09 03:00:37 18.00   MOR20   NaN
4   34.92   42.53   34.04   44.68   18.19   2017-10-09 03:47:11 18.19   MOR6    NaN


df.dtypes
bottom_temperature             float64
bottom_humidity                float64
top_temperature                float64
top_humidity                   float64
external_temperature           float64
published_at            datetime64[ns]
external_humidity              float64
short_id                        object
weight                         float64
dtype: object
```

Graph with vertical lines identifying switches:

```
# MOR4 - bottom and top sensors switched on aug 10 and switched back on 11th
fig, axarr = plt.subplots()

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.plot(df.loc[df['short_id'] == 'MOR4']['published_at'], df.loc[df['short_id'] == 'MOR4']['bottom_temperature'], label = "Bottom Temperature C") 
plt.plot(df.loc[df['short_id'] == 'MOR4']['published_at'], df.loc[df['short_id'] == 'MOR4']['top_temperature'], label = "Top Temperature") 
plt.plot(df.loc[df['short_id'] == 'MOR4']['published_at'], df.loc[df['short_id'] == 'MOR4']['bottom_humidity'], label = "Bottom Humidity %") 
plt.plot(df.loc[df['short_id'] == 'MOR4']['published_at'], df.loc[df['short_id'] == 'MOR4']['top_humidity'], label = "Top Humidity %") 
plt.plot(df.loc[df['short_id'] == 'MOR4']['published_at'], df.loc[df['short_id'] == 'MOR4']['weight'], label = "Weight kg") 


#add vertical line 
plt.axvline(datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 10, 13, 10))

#add vertical line 
plt.axvline(datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 11, 14, 10))

#specify date
axarr.set_xlim([datetime.date(2017, 8, 10), datetime.date(2017, 8, 12)])


#add title, legend
#plt.title('MOR1, Noticed on Aug 23')
axarr.legend(loc ='best',prop={'size': 6})

plt.show()
```

[image]

Question:

In the dataframe, how to switch the values of "bottom_humidity", "bottom_temperature" with "top_humidity", "bottom_humidity" between specified dates (first date: 2017-8-10, 13:10. Second date: 2017-8-11, 14:10?

In other words:

Between the two vertical lines, the green line is actually dark blue line and vice versa, and same applies to the light blue and red lines, and looking to change that in the dataframe between the two identified dates.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I edited post.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Just dumping data and requirements is very much frowned upon here.

Comment: It still seems unclear. The sensors were "twice at" what? Why do you want to swap those values? It's unclear from the graph why anything would need to be swapped with anything else; "bottom humidity" for example seems to have consistent values across both vertical lines.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, sensors that were misplaced during this day, so the "top sensors" were put in the "bottom" position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean mask to get the relevant rows:

```
m = (df['published_at'] >= '2017-8-10 13:10') & (df['published_at'] <= '2017-8-11 14:10') & (df['short_id'] == 'MOR4')
```

Then just switch the fields for those rows:

```
cols_orig = ['bottom_temperature', 'bottom_humidity', 'top_temperature', 'top_humidity']
cols_mod = ['top_temperature', 'top_humidity', 'bottom_temperature', 'bottom_humidity']

df.loc[m, cols_orig] = df.loc[m, cols_mod].values
```

Comment: This works for the entire dataset, not just the subset of df['short_id'] == 'MOR5'

Comment: Hmm, getting this error: TypeError: Could not compare ['2017-8-10 13:10'] with block values. i think it is maybe due to not having the exact date

Comment: thanks for your help. I just added dtypes, and code for the plot in OP

Comment: @Evan whoops forgot pandas matched indices when setting data... Adding `.values` should work (see updated answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways of going about it...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'top':   [5,6,3,4,5,  2,2,1,3,1,  7,6,5],
                   'bottom':[2,2,1,3,1,  5,6,3,4,5,  1,2,1],
                   'other': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]})
```

1) If top is always going to be greater than... then use max / min:

```
df['new_top'] = df[['top', 'bottom']].max(axis=1)
df['new_bottom'] = df[['top', 'bottom']].min(axis=1)
```

2) (*Very dirty*) Identify manually the points and build the columns:

```
df['new_top2']  = pd.concat([ df.iloc[:4]['top'], df.iloc[4:10]['bottom'], df.iloc[10:]['top'] ])
df['new_bottom2']  = pd.concat([ df.iloc[:4]['bottom'], df.iloc[4:10]['top'], df.iloc[10:]['bottom'] ])
```

Based on the limited information you have given, and that you haven't provided any of the things you've tried it's hard to give you a good answer...

Answer (score 1):

It makes things easier if you set the timestamp to be your index first:

```
data = data.set_index('published_at')
```

Then you can change problematic segments like this:

```
data.loc['2017-8-10 13:10':'2017-8-11 14:10','bottom_humidity'] = \
 data.loc['2017-8-10 13:10':'2017-8-11 14:10','top_humidity'].values
```

If you like, you can define a time slice for this and use it multiple times:

```
snafu = slice('2017-8-10 13:10','2017-8-11 14:10')
data.loc[snafu,'bottom_humidity'] = data.top_humidity     
data.loc[snafu,'bottom_temperature'] = data.top_temperature
```

Or swap values like this:

```
data.loc[snafu,['bottom_temperature','top_temperature'] = \
 data.loc[snafu,['top_temperature','bottom_temperature']].values
```

Comment: Getting this for the first idea "error: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" trying time slice now

Comment: Maybe your original index had duplicates. Try: data.index = data.published_at